# Custom Delegate Filter VC Swift5

Tags: delegates, swift5

I'm adding a custom delegate to my app and, for some reason, it is not working.
My app has a map where I show several markers of different company types. There is also a button that, once pressed, takes me to another viewController where the user can input some filters. The user then presses "Apply" which would pass the filtering data to the map viewController.
The issue here is that no data is being passed.
As reference I followed the guideline https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef which works perfectly fine.

Here is the full project code https://github.com/afernandes0001/Custom-Delegate

I use Firebase but code below just shows pieces related to the delegate.

mapViewController - you will notice that I added a print to the prepareForSegue. When first loading the app and clicking "Search" button it shows nav1 as nil (which is expected) but, if I click Search and Apply (in filterVC), that print is never done.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, FilterVCDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        map.register(MyAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "clinicDetailsSegue" {
            let clinicsDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! ClinicsDetailsViewController
            clinicsDetailsViewController.id = self.note.mapId
        } else if segue.identifier == "searchSegue" {
            print("segue call")
            let nav1 = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
            print("nav1 \(nav1)")
            if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController, let filterVC = nav.topViewController as? FilterViewController {
                filterVC.delegate = self
            }
      }
    }

    func chosenData(clinicNameFilter: String, stateFilter: String, cityFilter: String, esp1Filter: String, esp2Filter: String) {
        print("Received data \(clinicNameFilter), \(stateFilter), \(cityFilter), \(esp1Filter), \(esp2Filter)")
    }
}
```

FilterViewController

```
import UIKit

protocol FilterVCDelegate: class {
    func chosenData(clinicNameFilter: String, stateFilter: String, cityFilter: String, esp1Filter: String, esp2Filter: String)
}


class FilterViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    weak var delegate: FilterVCDelegate?

    var selectedName = ""

    var statesJSON = [Estado]()
    var cities = [Cidade]()
    var state : Estate? // Selected State identifier
    var city : City? // Selected City identifier
    var selectedState = "" // Used to retrieve info from Firebase
    var selectedCity = "" // Used to retrieve info from Firebase

    var specialtiesJSON = [Specialty]()
    var specialties2 = [Specialty2]()
    var specialty1 : Specialty? // Selected Specialty1 identifier
    var specialty2 : Specialty2? // Selected Specialty2 identifier
    var selectedSpecialty1 = ""
    var selectedSpecialty2 = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var clinicName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var esp1Picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var esp2Picker: UIPickerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        readJsonStates()
        readJsonSpecialties()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        clinicName.text = ""
    }


    @IBAction func applyFilter(_ sender: Any) {
        if clinicName.text == nil {
            clinicName.text = ""
        }

        if selectedState != "" {
            if selectedCity != "" {
                if selectedSpecialty1 != ""{
                    if selectedSpecialty2 != "" {

                       delegate?.chosenData(clinicNameFilter: clinicName.text!, stateFilter: selectedState, cityFilter: selectedCity, esp1Filter: selectedSpecialty1, esp2Filter: selectedSpecialty2)
                        let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
                        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2], animated: true)
                    } else {
                        print("Fill in all filter data")
                    }
                } else {
                        print("Fill in all filter data")
                }
            } else {
                         print("Fill in all filter data")
            }
        } else {
                        print("Fill in all filter data")
        }
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        esp1Picker.reloadComponent(0)
        esp2Picker.reloadComponent(0)
        statePicker.reloadAllComponents()

        if pickerView == statePicker {
            if component == 0 {
                self.state = self.statesJSON[row]
                self.coties = self.statesJSON[row].cities
                statePicker.reloadComponent(1)
                statePicker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
            } else {
                self.city = self.cities[row]
                statePicker.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        } else if pickerView == esp1Picker {
            self.specialty1 = self.specialtiesJSON[row]
            self.specialties2 = self.specialtiesJSON[row].specialty2
            esp1Picker.reloadComponent(0)
            esp2Picker.reloadComponent(0)
            esp2Picker.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

        } else if pickerView == esp2Picker {
            self.specialty2 = self.specialties2[row]
            esp1Picker.reloadComponent(0)
            esp2Picker.reloadComponent(0)
        }

        let indexSelectedState = statePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let indexSelectedCity = statePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let indexSelectedEsp1 = esp1Picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let indexSelectedEsp2 = esp2Picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)

        if indexSelectedState >= 0 {
            if indexSelectedCity >= 0 {
                selectedState = estadosJSON[indexSelectedState].name
                selectedCity = cidades[indexSelectedCity].name
            }
        }

        if indexSelectedEsp1 >= 0 {
            if indexSelectedEsp2 >= 0 {
                selectedSpecialty1 = specialtiesJSON[indexSelectedEsp1].name
                selectedSpecialty2 = specialtiesJSON[indexSelectedEsp1].specialty2[indexSelectedEsp2].name
            }
        }
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        if pickerView == statePicker {
            return 2
        } else if pickerView == esp1Picker {
            return 1
        } else if pickerView == esp2Picker {
            return 1
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == statePicker {
            if component == 0 {
                return statesJSON.count
            } else {
                return cities.count
            }
        } else if pickerView == esp1Picker {
            return self.specialtiesJSON.count

        } else if pickerView == esp2Picker {
            return specialties2.count
        }
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        var rowTitle = ""
        let pickerLabel = UILabel()

        pickerLabel.textColor = UIColor.black

        if pickerView == statePicker {
            if component == 0 {
                rowTitle = statesJSON[row].name
            } else {
                rowTitle = cities[row].name
            }
        } else if pickerView == esp1Picker {
            rowTitle = specialtiesJSON[row].name
        } else if pickerView == esp2Picker {
            rowTitle = specialties2[row].name
        }

        pickerLabel.text = rowTitle
        pickerLabel.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: 16.0)
        pickerLabel.textAlignment = .center

        return pickerLabel
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if pickerView == statePicker {
            if component == 0 {
                return 50
            } else {
                return 300
            }
        }
        return 300
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func readJsonStates() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "StatesAndCities", withExtension: "json")!
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let jsonResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootState.self, from: data)

            //handles the array of countries on your json file.
            self.statesJSON = jsonResult.state
            self.cities = self.statesJSON.first!.cities

        } catch {

        }
    }

    func readJsonSpecialties() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Specialties", withExtension: "json")!
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            let jsonResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootEsp.self, from: data)

            //handles the array of specialties on your json file.
            self.specialtiesJSON = jsonResult.specialty
            self.specialties2 = self.specialtiesJSON.first!.specialty2
        } catch {
        }
    }

}
```

Any idea why, when I click ApplyFilter, delegate is not updated in the MapViewController?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my project. 
The issue was with my Navigation Controller.

When I posted the error above, my Storyboard looked like the below

[image: Previous storyboard]

To make it work, I added the Navigation Controller to the Filter View Controller as below

[image]

That did the work and protocol is working as expected.